# Why (\x)^2 and \x^2 produce different results in Tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

`(\x)^2` will plot correct parabola, while `\x^2` will have negative x branch upside down. Why () are required for this formula to work?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-4.1,-4.1) grid (4.1,4.1);
        \draw[->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-4.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

        \draw[thick,purple,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.5*\x^2});
        \draw[thick,brown,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.2*\x^3});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\caption{$y=1/2 x^2, y=1/5 x^3$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the parenthesis are required to properly square negative numbers. So, `-5^2` will be `-25`.

Comment: Slap on the forehead! Right! I am forgetting that this is not a true 'programming' language but macros. This means I gotta be careful in the future and overdoing parenthesis will not hurt :)

Comment: @Peter sounds like that comment could make a pretty good answer.

Comment: @ajeh In most _true_ 'programming' languages, the power operator has higher priority than unary minus operator. TikZ is not an exception.

Comment: :) In most true programming languages, minus operator would not be a factor, as variable resolution is not pre-processed: x^2 would not be translated into -5^2 when x=-5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `()` are required so that exponents are properly applied to negative numbers.  Otherwise we have `-5^2=-25`. Here is the output with and without the applied parenthesis:

[image]

### Notes:

- Even though this will only be an issue with even exponents, I would recommend always using parenthesis `(\x)`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-4.1,-4.1) grid (4.1,4.1);
        \draw[->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-4.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

        \draw[thick,purple,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.5*\x^2}) node [right] {INCORRECT};
        \draw[thick,brown,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.2*\x^3}) ;
       
        
    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-4.1,-4.1) grid (4.1,4.1);
        \draw[->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-4.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

        \draw[ultra thick,purple,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.5*(\x)^2}) node [right] {CORRECT};
        \draw[ultra thick,brown,domain=-3:3,smooth] plot (\x,{0.2*(\x)^3});
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```